# DataContractSerializer inheritance backward compatibility

Tags: c#, inheritance, serialization, datacontractserializer, datacontract

I have a baseApplicationClass
and MyApplicationClass deriving from it.

since I need to add another level of inheritance between them, I need to move one of the properties which is a DataMember.

so this is the old inheritance tree which is serialized to file using dataContract:

BaseApplicationClass -> MyApllicationClass

I need to add another level of inheritance between them
New inheritance tree:

BaseApplicationClass -> **SpcialApplicationClass** ->MyApplicationClass

I need to move one of the properties which is a DataMember, from MyApplicationClass to SpcialApplicationClass.

I understand that breaking the inheritance tree might break the serializtion process, is there anyway to support such a change?

Deserializing the old inheritance structure to the new one? I noticed that there are no new properties.